# Override a default method using lambdas

Tags: java, lambda

Given a simple interface with a default method:

```
private interface A {
    default void hello() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

And a method that accepts an instance of it:

```
private static void print(A a) {
    a.hello();
}
```

I can override this using an anonymous class:

```
print(new A() {
    @Override
        public void hello() {
        System.out.println("OverHello");
    }
});
```

but if I try with a lambda `print(() -> System.out.println("OverHello2"));`, I get a compilation error.

> No target method found

Is there a way to make the override with a lambda?

Comment: Can you post the `A` interface, please?

Comment: private interface A{default void hello(){System.out.println("A");}}

Comment: can you post error which you have?

Comment: Try putting the @FunctionalInterface annotation on your interface.  You'll see that you get a compiler error.  A functional interface must have one, and only one, abstract method (a default method is not abstract).

Comment: In "print()" i have "The method print(DefTest.A) in the type DefTest is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {})", DefTest is the class name, and in the lambda argument "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, because your interface does not have exactly one unimplemented method (that a lambda could provide the implementation for).

See [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas don't allow overriding default methods.  This was an intentional design choice as it allows functional interfaces (interfaces that can be instantiated via a lambda) to have one or more default methods.

To successfully allow A to be instantiated via a lambda, you cannot have a default definition for `hello()`.